# Make jQuery dataTables responsive to different window sizes

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

This is more of a basic CSS question, I think. I have tried many things, but am curious how to make `GridView_OrderNew_wrapper` responsive. Code...

**HTML**

```
<div id="main" class="main">

        <div class="row mainRows">

            <div id="mainRowTopLeft" class="col-6 quads">

                <div id="topLeftTableContainer" class="tableContainer">

                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView_OrderNew" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDS_OrderNew" CssClass="hover nowrap compact">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="StrItemDesc" HeaderText="StrItemDesc" SortExpression="StrItemDesc" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="StrSisfinPO" HeaderText="StrSisfinPO" SortExpression="StrSisfinPO" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="StrBudgetCode" HeaderText="StrBudgetCode" SortExpression="StrBudgetCode" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="IntQuantity" HeaderText="IntQuantity" SortExpression="IntQuantity" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <div id="footer">                            

                    </div>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="Order_Selection" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="hide"></asp:TextBox>

                </div>

            </div>

   <div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#2e9ef2;
}

.mainRows {
    position: relative;    
    height: 45vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color:azure;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.quads {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.tableContainer {    
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    height: 95%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#GridView_OrderNew_wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

As you may be able to tell, I am trying to make `#GridView_OrderNew_wrapper` responsive to `tableContainer`. Where/how can I allow the table to respond to different window sizes?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Where is `GridView_OrderNew_wrapper` in your html?

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski `GridView_OrderNew_wrapper` is created by jQuery dataTables. It is not in my coded HTML, but it is rendered HTML in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is using webforms... You should use MVC instead, but that is another topic. :)

This is what I use... This will render the original datatable normal and when the screen width gets small enough will apply flex box css rulles and collapse everything nicely... This also does not only work with datatables but will work with any table...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    tr {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
        border: 1px solid rgba(3,3,3,0.2);
    }

    td, th {
        flex: 1 1 150px;
        border: 0.5px solid rgba(3,3,3,0.2);
    }  
}
```